# SwiftUI: Preserve ObservedObject between renders

Tags: swiftui, observableobject

I've just come across an unfortunate issue with my code:

```swift
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    func load() {
        // set up Combine subscriptions, etc.
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = MyViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        SomeChildView()
            .onAppear { self.viewModel.load() }
    }
}
```

I have many views that are structured this way. (some) State and logic are offloaded to a view model, which is initialized in `onAppear`.

The problem is that the view may be re-rendered, but the `onAppear` is only executed once. The result is that anytime the view is re-rendered one or more times, none of the state in the view model is actually reflected in the view, because only the first instance had its `load()` method called.

There are a few ways around this, but all of them have drawbacks:

- I could move the logic in `load()` into `init()`, but that seems smelly because `init()` is for simple things like property assignments, not for setting up subscriptions or other external access. Moreover, I want to be able to override the view model logic for use in tests, and `init()` can't be overridden. EDIT: The bigger issue here is that we only want to perform the load logic once when the view appears, not every time the view renders.
- I could pass the view model in from the parent, but that may suffer from the same problem if the parent is re-rendered.
- I could initialize the view model in `SceneDelegate` and pass it in as an `@EnvironmentObject`, but the view model is stateful and needs to be reinitialized every time the view reappears, so it would be best and easiest to not have to tie it to some "global" store.

I feel like there's a simple way to achieve this that I'm just missing. Thinking outside the box, the reason I'm using view models at all is for separation of concerns and for ease of unit testing. I want the view to just interact with the interface provided by the view model, and the view model can handle all the messy data access. I'm also not sure if there is another way to subscribe to a Combine `Publisher` without using an `ObservableObject`.

Comment: Problem is not clear. Would you provide specific demo code?

Comment: `@EnvironmentObject` *is* very much intended for stateful models.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I've understood your question, but for second option in your list there is a way to ensure that re-render of parent will not destroy the data - you can use @StateObject instead of @ObservedObject there:

```
@StateObject private var viewModel = MyViewModel()
```

and then pass it to child's @ObservedObject property

Comment: @StateObject isn't available in iOS 13 :-(.  Is there another solution?